# If posts category is "cars", display image

Tags: categories

Can someone translate this:

If posts category is "cars" show image

**For example:**

I have an article with category 'car' and another article with category 'banana'. No I'm looking for a way to add an car image to every article with 'car' category. And banana image to every article with 'banana' category. For default (if article has no category) I want to show the same car image.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. We have a one question per post policy, and you are asking two. Please post the second question as a new question. Please also take your time and see [ask], [help] and also visit the [tour] page :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the conditional tag [`has_catgeory`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category). You can do something like this

```
if(has_category( 'cars' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) {
    //display cars image
}elseif(has_category( 'banana' )) {
    //display banana image
}
```

From your comments, here is your code

```
<?php if(has_category( 'Update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) { ?>
    <img alt="Hello!" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/loud.png"> 
<?php } elseif(has_category( 'Event' )) { ?>
    <img alt="Hello!" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/event.png"> 
<?php } ?>
```

**EDIT**

The conditional tag [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) can also be used for this purpose

**EDIT 2**

For the second part of your question, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8390175/1908141) by @JohannesPille on SO. Here is the post reposted.

***PLEASE NOTE:*** I did upvote the answer on SO. If anyone see this as unfit, please rollback this edit :-)

The action `create_category` runs when a new category is created.

You want your category creation function to run when the theme is activated. The relevant action is [`after_setup_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category).

Drop this in your theme's *functions.php* and you should be good to go:

```
function create_my_cat () {
    if (file_exists (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php')) {
        require_once (ABSPATH.'/wp-admin/includes/taxonomy.php'); 
        if ( ! get_cat_ID( 'Testimonials' ) ) {
            wp_create_category( 'Testimonials' );
        }
    }
}
add_action ( 'after_setup_theme', 'create_my_cat' );
```

Comment: @peter so my code should look like this?<?php
                            if(has_category( 'Update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) {
                                <img alt="Hello!" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/loud.png">
                            }

                            elseif(has_category( 'Event' )) {
                                <img alt="Hello!" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/event.png">
                            }
                        ?>

Comment: @Paul Please see my update, your code in your comments does not use proper php opening and closing tags which will result in a synatx error. I have corrected it and posted it in my answer

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

The proper control structure would be a [`switch case`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php), it makes for more readable and maintainable code. Here is an example within a loop.

```
<ol class="news-list">
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="post-date">
                    <?php 
                        $category = get_the_category();

                        switch ($category[0]->term_id){
                            // display an icon next to the news item, according to the category.
                            // more icons: http://fontawesome.io/icon/

                            case 3:
                            // private item
                            ?>
                            <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                            <?
                            break;

                            case 18:
                            // Headteachers' blog item
                            ?>
                            <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
                            <?
                            break;

                            default:
                            ?>
                            <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
                            <?
                            break;

                            } 
                            the_time('j F Y'); ?>
                </span>
                <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
                <p class="post-resume"><?php html5wp_excerpt('html5wp_index','empty_readmore_link'); ?></p>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ol>
```

Comment: Please properly add your code. Please honor readability